# C Regex capturing group

Tags: c, regex, parsing

I'm having troubles understanding how the regex in C work.
Basically I have an XML file (I can't use an XML parser) containing lines like this:

```
<Node Bla="blabla" Name="this is my name" .... />
<Node Name="this is my name" Bla="blabla" .... />
```

What I would like to do is extract the name part of each line. So far I have been using the following regex:

```
char *regex_str = "Name=\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

But this gives me Name="this is my name", I'm only looking for the ***this is my name*** part.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The flippant "I can't use an XML parser" makes [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) almost a necessity, I think. :)

Comment: I'm completely aware that this is no way the best way to proceed, and believe me if I could use an XML parsing library I would. However I am relatively confident I can "parse" the file safely since:
- The XML structure is flat
- The XML file is dynamically generated and isn't to be edited by users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need a capturing group.

Assuming your library has lookbehind (which it definitely does if it's PCRE), you can use this regex to match the name:

```
(?<=[Nn]ame=")[^"]+
```

See [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/3).

**Explanation**

- the lookbehind `(?<=[Nn]ame=")` asserts that what precedes is `Name="` or `name="`
- `[^"]+` matches one or more chars that are not a `"`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookbehind to capture the characters which are just after to the string `Name` upto the first `"` symbol,

```
(?<=Name=\")([^\"]*)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=Name=\")` Sets the matching marker just after to the string `Name"`
- `([^\"]*)` Captures all the characters not of `"` zero or more times.